# 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'note'

Tags: ios, swift

Looking for a bit more help. I have a self declared object, where I have two properties 'date and note'. in the code below date can be referenced in an instanciated object fine but note cannot. Any ideas?

Here is the detail view controller where the errors are. Line 10 and 20.

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var tView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
tView.text = allNotes[currentNoteIndex].note
tView.becomeFirstResponder()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if tView.text == "" {
        allNotes.removeObjectAtIndex(currentNoteIndex)
    }
    else {
        allNotes[currentNoteIndex].note = tView.text
    }
    Note.saveNotes()
    noteTable?.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Here is the note.swift file where you can see the Variables.

```
import UIKit

var allNotes:NSMutableArray = []
var currentNoteIndex:Int = -1
var noteTable:UITableView?

let KAllNotes:String = "notes"


class Note: NSObject {
var date:String
var note:String

override init() {
    date = NSDate().description
    note = ""
}

func dictionary() -> NSDictionary {
    return ["note":note, "date":date]
}

class func saveNotes() {
    var aDictionaries:NSMutableArray = []
    for var i:Int = 0; i < allNotes.count; i++ {
        aDictionaries.addObject(allNotes[i].dictionary())
    }
//        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(aDictionaries, forKey: KAllNotes)
    aDictionaries.writeToFile(filePath(), atomically: true)
}

class func loadnotes() {
    var defaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
//        var savedData:[NSDictionary]? = defaults.objectForKey(KAllNotes) as? [NSDictionary]
    var savedData:NSArray? = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath())
    if let data:NSArray = savedData {
        for var i:Int = 0; i < data.count; i++ {
            var n:Note = Note()
            n.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(data[i] as! [NSDictionary : AnyObject])
            allNotes.addObject(n)
        }
    }
}

class func filePath() -> String {
    var d:[String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]
    if let directories:[String] = d {
        var docsDirectory:String = directories[0]
        var path:String = docsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(KAllNotes).notes")
        return path;
    }
    return ""
}
}
```

Comment: This is happening because you are using an NSMutableArray to store your notes, which is not typed. So from here you have two options really. 1. Store your notes in a Swift array of type `Array<Note>` (`[Note]`). 2. Cast your object as a Note before accessing its properties. I would also suggest storing your notes in an alternative way instead of using global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you declared `allNotes` as `NSMutableArray`, the compiler has no way of knowing the type of its elements, so every object will be considered as `AnyObject`.

You need to provide to the compiler the information that `allNotes` contains objects of type `Note`.

You can either cast the object when retrieving it from the array

```
(allNotes[currentNoteIndex] as! Note).note
```

or (preferably) use a typed swift array

```
var allNotes: [Note] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `allNotes` is not type of `Note`. So for safety reasons you must declare `var allNotes:NSMutableArray = []` as `var allNotes = [Note]()`

Comment: Consider adding some explanation for why this is required, @Bluehound's comment touches on this.